# Has there been any studies or economic theories regarding HSA and whether to save/spend

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, hsa

HSA have triple tax advantage:

1. Pre-tax contributions
2. Tax-free growth
3. Tax-free withdrawals for medical expenses

If one planned to **only** use this money for medical expenses after retirement (62), is it advantageous economically to use *current* after tax dollars to pay for current medical expenses and allow HSA to grow tax-free?

How does paying current medical expenses with after-tax dollars figure into the equation?

What would conditions could change answer? (Assumption 6% growth/ 3% inflation vs 12% growth/ and 10% inflation)

How realistic would be to pay with future dollars for medical expenses years later after inflation has ate away at medical expense from previous years?

How does a time horizon play into this? (30/40/50 year old saving until retirement)

How realistic is to assume tax-free withdrawals and tax-free growth for extended years?e.g. politics